# Would it be possible to use AI to measure pupil dilation diameters and fluctuation, on video films on a regular webcam?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, image-processing

I've been researching the topic of Cognitive Load Measurement through pupil dilation measurement. All solutions to pupil dilation measurement require some kind of special hardware setup. I was wondering if it would be possible to use AI on a regular webcam record and do those measurements later. If yes, I'd love some pointers to resources of what I need to know to be able to implement it.

Comment: The issue requring specialist kit may be a scale/zoom/focus issue from the raw image, as opposed to any smart processing in the specialist kit. A good rule of thumb is if a human could perform the analysis somehow from the image source you want to use, then so could an AI trained to perform the same task. Do you have any links/research that show how to measure pupil dilation from webcam images or similar - perhaps as some kind of post analysis from a video?

Comment: Yeah, that was my rationale. By all means, it seems like a task that could be accomplished by a human. From a conference paper:

Comment: (continuing)... "A Study on Algorithms of pupil diameter measurement" I saw you could combine algorithms that can perform such tasks in a picture. What I wanted to understand - and maybe it is a layman question - is if there would be ways to optimize those algorithms using machine learning techniques.